# express.static() doesn't route the static files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

While working on an express project, I am trying to use `express.static()` function.

I've added a static route in my main file:

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const ApiResponse = require('./utils/response');
const userRoutes = require('./routes/lottery');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({ extended: false }));

app.use(userRoutes);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './', 'views', 'src', 'index.js')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './', 'views', 'src', 'style.css')));


app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  ApiResponse.error(res, err);
});

app.listen(8080);
```

**lottery.js (router.js)**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const LotteryController = require('../controllers/LotteryController');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'views', 'index.html'));
});

router.post('/simulate', LotteryController.simulate);

router.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
  const err = new Error('message: Endpoint not found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I load my localhost:8080 page - my index.js and style.css files are not connecting and show me the following mistake:

**GET http://localhost:8080/src/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)**

This is a tree of my project folder:

```
public
├───views
|   └───src
|   |    ├─── style.css
|   |    └─── index.js
|   |
|   └─ index.html
|
└───app.js
```

Comment: Are you sure you want the `src` portion of the url?

Comment: `index.js` and `style.css` are located in src directory

Answer (score 2):

I would just serve the public folder.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Then you can just do:

```
http://localhost:8080/views/src/index.js
```

Comment: i've deleted my answer because this one is best instead of setting static files one by one.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem.

The problem was in the wrong order, express.static() have been calling after routing function.

Here is a correct version:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'src')));
app.use(userRoutes);
```

Comment: That makes sense. Your app.js is in the public directory making that the root of the application.